# MYSQL: Trigger only calls SP the first time

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I made this trigger and it only calls the stored procedure the first time. I want to be able to create several logs just from one operation and thats why I want to invoke "InsertLog" several times.

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `mydb`.`Cultura_AFTER_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT ON `mydb`.`Cultura`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE idOperação INT;
    DECLARE operação VARCHAR(6);
    DECLARE tabela VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE idObjecto VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE coluna VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE valor VARCHAR(300);

    SELECT MAX(idOperação) + 1 INTO idOperação FROM Log;
    IF idOperação IS NULL THEN
    SET idOperação = 1;
END IF; 
    SET operação = "INSERT";
    SET tabela = "Cultura";
    SET idObjecto = CAST(new.id AS CHAR);

    IF (new.Email <> NULL) THEN
        SET coluna = 'Email';
        SET valor = new.Email;
        CALL InsertLog(idOperação, operação, tabela, idObjecto, coluna, valor);
    END IF;

    IF (new.Nome <> NULL) THEN
        SET coluna = 'Nome';
        SET valor = new.Nome;
        CALL InsertLog(idOperação, operação, tabela, idObjecto, coluna, valor);
    END IF;

    IF (new.Descrição <> NULL) THEN
        SET coluna = 'Descrição';
        SET valor = new.Descrição;
        CALL InsertLog(idOperação, operação, tabela, idObjecto, coluna, valor);
    END IF;

END
```

Comment: <> null should be is not null?

Comment: Your logic may be incorrect (hard to say without seeing the procedure and insertlog definition) but you are incrementing  idOperação once but you may have more than 1 change per row - I'm not sure if your intention was to generate a row in insertlog for each of the 3 possible changes or 1 row for all possible changes.